# How to get last *executed* command

Tags: vimrc

To get the most recent command I can do:

```
:<ctrl-p>
```

Or:

```
:<up>
```

However, this will also show commands that might have been typed in, but weren't run, for example, I may recently typed in:

```
:call TypoFuNCt
```

But not actually executed it. And then if I go back and press us, it will fill in that last-entered text. Is there a way to skip not-entered-commands in the ctrl-n/p or elsewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last typed & executed command is stored in the "colon"-register (`:h quote:`). You can input its value while editing the command-line by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> (`:h c_CTRL-R`).

Or you can just re-run this command by typing `:@:` in the command-line.

Comment: Do you need the first colon? I think bare `@:` will do the trick

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You mean `@:` in Normal mode? Yes, and this one too. Just not sure if the OP wants a Normal mode command as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would have left this as just a comment on Matt's OP, but I don't have the rep for it.

EDIT: It seems to be an edge case just with my machine; an autocmd silently fails upon CTRL-F, and the history gets saved even though what was typed does not get executed. I can confirm that CTRL-F normally will not cause ": from getting saved. For reference, it's a checktime-on-focus-gained autocmd.

This was wrong:

> At least on my machine,  `":` does **not** contain the last *executed* command, but the last-typed & executed, or last-typed & CTRL-F'd (which goes to cmdlinewin mode). It doesn't have to be executed.

> However this is a very small corner case, because if you ESC out of the cmdline without executing, the register is not filled. (which works according to rational expectations)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Some references: `:help quote:`, `:help c_<Esc>` and `c_CTRL-C` just below it, and of course `:help cmdline-window`.

Comment: Thanks! ツ It seems to be an edge case with my machine; an autocmd silently fails upon CTRL-F, and the history gets saved even though what was typed does not get executed. I can confirm that CTRL-F normally will not cause ": from getting saved. For reference, it's a checktime-on-focus-gained autocmd.